# HTML 5 sockets running on Google app engine for php

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, sockets, websocket

I'm investigating the possibility to use Google App engine for my website.

Is it possible to run HTML5 sockets in combination with php sockets? So i can create a user chat and live updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you can design your solution around the [Socket PHP API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/) you're in luck.  That's all that's available on the AppEngine PHP server.